# Base64 string image data show in IE?

Tags: asp.net, html, internet-explorer, base64

I have a base64 string and i need to show it in my IE browser i tried with appending the

> data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAOALMAAOazToeHh0tLS/7LZv/0jvb29t/f3//Ub/
>   /ge8WSLf/rhf/3kdbW1mxsbP//mf///yH5BAAAAAAALAAAAAAQAA4AAARe8L1Ekyky67QZ1hLnjM5UUde0ECwLJoExKcpp

the above syntax it works fine in Firefox but does not work in IE ??
Any idea how d o i make my image be shown ? I am trying to set the src attribute from my code asp.net page code.

Thanks

Comment: what is the real image look like?

Comment: Which version of IE? How are you showing it where?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work in IE

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,<YOUR DATA>" alt="Base64 encoded image" width="150" height="150"/>
```

IE limits this in-line size to 32KB..

But there seems to be something wrong with your base64 data. It does not work on my tests in chrome,IE or anything.

http://jsfiddle.net/ppumkin/5JAjh/

Comment: The image is transparent for me in Chrome and Firefox, doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Hi , That was just some dummy data not real . Thanks for helping out and sorry for the incorrect base64 data . I got this to working i think the inline size made the difference so i got a thumbnail of my image and then the base64 of that and it started working now . So thanks Once again !!